# Execute command in terminal on click event

Tags: terminal, productivity

Recently I got to know a decent feature that exists in iTerm2, namely you can configure what command can be invoked while clicking on a text that refers a file. (e.g. you can open this file in text editor). My question is if there is chance to configure similar functionality in linux terminal?